# How can I get the printed message from streamlink.streams() when it still returns 200?

Tags: python, streamlink

[image]

As you can see in the image above: I'm getting these Error messages from the youtube plugin. I want to be able to get from the streamlink.streams() method this error message so I can send it to my frontend.

I tried using a Try Except, but as you can see in the image above the method is always returning a "{}" (dict) and 200 (success). Is there any way I could get the printed value that is being showed in console by that method?

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code, including required imports and package names?